# SQL Server DMV - sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats - What do these columns mean?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-management-views

I am tinkering with creating a query to find missing indexes. I've taken a base query created by the Red-Gate folks in their SQL Server DMV Starter Pack eBook and am modifying it a bit. There are a couple columns in `sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats` which I don't know how to interpret. They are:

```
avg_total_user_cost
avg_user_impact
```

According to documentation I found avg_total_user_cost is defined as ***Represents the average total user cost each time when the user query was executed***. And, avg_user_impact ***Represents the value as a percentage. It shows the amount of improvement which you can get if the index is created.***

An index my query says should be added shows a 2.22 average user cost and a 99.82 user impact. What do these numbers really mean? Does this mean by adding an index, I can improve the speed of the associated query by 99.82%. I have no clue what 2.22 might mean.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got a nice query to find missing indexes?

Comment: there is a good one here: http://www.geniiius.com/blog/missing-indexes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My interpretation of these has been that:

- `avg_total_user_cost` is the current 
  average of all queries that could 
  potentially benefit from the creation
  of the missing index group. The "cost" is a
  unitless value calculated by the 
  optimizer. See: [SQL SERVER – Execution Plan – Estimated I/O Cost – Estimated CPU Cost – No Unit](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/01/22/sql-server-execution-plan-estimated-io-cost-estimated-cpu-cost-no-unit/)
- `avg_user_impact` is a percentage
  representing the average decrease in cost of all queries
  if the missing index group was created. The
  higher the percentage, the greater
  the benefit of the new index will be.

Answer (score 5):

@Joe's answer seems right, I'm just adding some possibly-useful info:

There's an article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn369873.aspx) that uses this calculation to give an overal impact value:

```
avg_total_user_cost * avg_user_impact * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans))
```

Here's the query they suggest:

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar, getdate(), 126) AS runtime, 
    mig.index_group_handle, mid.index_handle, 
    CONVERT (decimal (28,1), migs.avg_total_user_cost * migs.avg_user_impact * 
            (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans)) AS improvement_measure, 
    'CREATE INDEX missing_index_' + CONVERT (varchar, mig.index_group_handle) + '_' + 
              CONVERT (varchar, mid.index_handle) + ' ON ' + mid.statement + ' 
              (' + ISNULL (mid.equality_columns,'') 
              + CASE WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL 
                          AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL 
                     THEN ',' ELSE '' END + ISNULL (mid.inequality_columns, '')
              + ')' 
              + ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS create_index_statement, 
    migs.*, 
    mid.database_id, 
    mid.[object_id]
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups AS mig
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats AS migs 
    ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details AS mid 
    ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
ORDER BY migs.avg_total_user_cost * migs.avg_user_impact * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) DESC
```

The resulting `improvement_measure` is unitless, i.e. only useful in a relative sense, but this should help combine the different values from `dm_db_missing_index_group_stats` into something useful to make decisions from.

Comment: see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/241588/52150 for adding in stored procedure index optimization